# Products being removed from Categories automatically - Magento 1.9

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

On Magento 1.9.2 we have been having this strange problem:

I will add products to a category, reindex, flush cache, check on the front end, etc and the next day, some (not all) of the newly added products will mysteriously vanish from the category, no longer listed under that category on either the front end or the back end.

The first time it happened, I assumed that I had just screwed up, so I readded the products in the Manage Categories section and made sure to reindex. The second time, I added the categories to the individual products manage categories and then reindexed. The third time, I thought maybe I had to check that the products were both added on the Manage Categories section of the back end AND the manage categories section of the individual product page in the back end. So i dutifully did that, and reindexed after the changes to the categories for each product. It didn't help. Nothing has helped. The products refuse to stay in the categories.

Comment: if you done any recent changes , revert back..... is it happening for all products ? did you installed any extensions ? check is they any doubtfull users created under `system > permission > users` also this [site](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=newest) may help better.....

Comment: it is happening from last many days. we don't know why happening. it is happening for all categories product.
we have checked with one by one cron and extension.
but can't find any solution.

Comment: when product removed after indexing or next day automatically?